# Add <> () and spaces after function names automatically in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core

In ReSharper () and <> and spaces automatically add after function name

Can vs do that?

For example when we want to write "Console.Writeline"
If we use ReSharper () automatically add
But in vs we have to type manually

Comment: VS 2022 and older has no native functionality to do that.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliCode completion in VS2022 can help you in a way. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/type-less-code-more-with-intellicode-completions/

You can hit tab tab to accept it or use the up and down keys to select other options you like and then hit tab to complete the code.

[image]
[image]